# Two tests works individually but not together

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I have two tests in separate classes which test similar behaviors :

1. Adding product in bookmark with `Client()`.
2. Adding product in bookmark with ORM.

Individually, it's working :

```
./manage.py test compare.test.CompareBookmarkTests
```

or

```
./manage.py test compare.test.CompareAccountTests
```

They fail when they are launched together :

```
./manage.py test
```

I tried to :

- use `setUp` and `tearDown` methods
- change order of classes and methods
- use --reverse in my attempts to diagnose the issue
- launch lines of code in interactive django shell with a test database (and it's working)
- make some print debugging, my objects are correctly called from test database.
- merge those two classes in one

I haven't found relevant answers on stackoverflow, for now. Neither in django documentation.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Bookmark, Categorie, Product


class CompareBookmarkTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Categorie.objects.create(id_categorie='someid', name='somename')
        p = Categorie.objects.get(pk='someid')
        p.product_set.create(id_product='1', product_name='orange', categorie='someid')
        User.objects.create_user('john@sign.in', 'john@sign.in', 'smith')

    def tearDown(self):
        User.objects.all().delete()
        Categorie.objects.all().delete()
        Bookmark.objects.all().delete()

    def test_redirect_logged(self):
        self.client.login(username='john@sign.in', password='smith')

        # Adding product with id 1 in bookmark
        response = self.client.get('/compare/1/bookmark/')

        # Get added product form bookmark
        bookmark = Bookmark.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(str(bookmark), 'Bookmark object (1)')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


class CompareAccountTests(TestCase):
    def setUp/tearDown: [same as previous class]

    def test_get_product(self):
        self.client.login(username='john@sign.in', password='smith')

        user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
        product = Product.objects.get(pk='1')

        # Adding product with id 1 in bookmark
        add_bookmark = Bookmark.objects.create(id_result=product, user=user)

        bookmark = Bookmark.objects.get(pk=1)
        response = self.client.get('/compare/account/')
        self.assertEqual(str(bookmark), 'Bookmark object (1)')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I expect both my tests to succeed when launch together but I get :

`compare.models.Bookmark.DoesNotExist: Bookmark matching query does not exist.`

With --reverse :

`django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist`

It's probably a beginner mistake, but I can't see it, thanks for help !

Comment: It is not a good idea to rely on concrete IDs in the tests as DB sequences might not be cleared after a test and you will create an object object with `pk=2`. Try to rewrite your test without using concrete pk values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure to understand entirely your suggestion : for example, should I get my object by another field instead of pk value? If so, I tried it with no success, and during my experiments I also tried to find any duplicate possibly created between two tests. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: No, use pk, but do not expect that pk will always be `1`, `2` or something else. If you need to get access to object's pk created in `setUp` you can store object into `self` and use it later in the test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was probably causing the issue :

I used `psql` and I found test databases that were not deleted :

```
test_myprojet_1
test_myprojet_2
test_myprojet_3
test_myprojet_4
...and so on...
```

In addition to a very strange one :

```
test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test_myprojec[truncated name]
```

I used in `psql`:

```sql
DROP DATABASE [name];
```

Now, my tests are working as expected !

Thanks to [awesoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1532460/awesoon), your suggestion put me on the path.